# Script does not start when OS start|reboot

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6, upstart, init

I have a file at `/etc/init/pdoneVendorBroker.conf` with the following content:

```
description "PDone Vendor Broker"

start on runlevel [234]
stop on runlevel [0156]

respawn
exec php /var/bundles/pdoneVendorBroker/vendorBroker.php
post-start script
    PID=`status pdoneVendorBroker | egrep -oi '([0-9]+)$' | head -n1`
    echo $PID > /var/run/pdoneVendorBroker.pid
end script

post-stop script
    rm -f /var/run/pdoneVendorBroker.pid
end script
```

But script doesn't start at OS boot at least I should see `php /var/bundles/pdoneVendorBroker/vendorBroker.php` running in background as a process, right? Well, is not running and I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you do `initctl start vendorBroker` manually?

Comment: @jordanm Yes, I got this output `pdoneVendorBroker start/running, process 22548` is it running at that point? Also I can't see it running as a background proccess under `ps -ax` command output, why?

Comment: I'd try taking the 5 out of your `stop on runlevel` stanza. That usually means full X and networking mode, but I understand it can be distro dependent.